# Python: how to costumize a list of colors based on alist of values?

Tags: python

I have a list of values `l`

```
l = []
for i in range(0,1000):
    l.append(random.randint(0,100))
```

I would like to associate to each value a color with a colorbar between `0` and `100`

I would like to create a list of colors associated to each value.

Comment: You question is not clear to me. Can you explain more?

Comment: @ShafikurRahman I would like to associate to each value a color that depends on the value itself. For instance using a grayscale the value `0` corresponds to `white` and the value `1` corresponds to black while `0.5` to gray.

Comment: can you give sample list. You desired input/output value?

Comment: `randint` (if you're using `random.randint`) does not return a list. Do you mean `range(0, 100)`?

Comment: Color is with 3 coordinates `RGB`, so do you want something like `{1:[2,200,150], 2:[255,255,0]`...

Comment: @DanielDiekmeier I made a mistake before now I made the correction

Comment: It is not clear which color you want to associate with each number and how you want to represent colors (other than shades of gray).

Answer (score 0):

you should use `dict` to solve you problem.

```
color_dict = {
    '1' : {'rgb': '201:12:255'},
    '2' : {'rgb': '11:16:25'},
    '3' : {'rgb': '21:122:25'}
    .
    .
    .
    .
    '100' : {'rgb': '210:2:205'}
}
```

Now the logic for selection depends upon you and also the structure depends upon you to select the color.

Comment: I know but I would like to do it automatically